# I am trying to get in productname insted of productid in URL's parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I have links with two varialbes in it:

```
www.mysite.com/temporary/products.php?catid=1&productid=1
```

Which I am trying to make it:

```
www.mysite.com/temporary/products.php/category-name/product-name
```

Comment: What have you done so far? The two links in your question wont help you much. Post complete thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, why don't you work and think a little bit.

Follow these steps (Only applicable for you)

In your .htaccess do something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /temporary/products.php?category-name=$1&product-name=$2 [L]
// In above $1 = the Category Name and $2 = Product Name that you want to show
```

If you need the product id, then you can use pho GET metod to grab the category-name and product-name and make a function to grab ids from names like

```
public function getIdFromName($name) 
{
 $id = // your PDO SELECT
 return $id;
}
```